# How to Create DropdownButton with a list of JSON data within a list in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Using the example in [How to Create DropdownButton with a list of JSON Data and I want it to populate my DropDownButton in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51553962/how-to-create-dropdownbutton-with-a-list-of-json-data-and-i-want-it-to-populate) I have created the following working example:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final String jsonData =
      '[{"id":"e20c","name":"Apples","type":"fruit"},{"id":"a24e","name":"Oranges","type":"fruit"},{"id":"f2a0","name":"Bananas","type":"fruit"}]';
  List<FruitResponse> _fruitResponse = [];
  String selectedName;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final json = JsonDecoder().convert(jsonData);
    _fruitResponse = (json)
        .map<FruitResponse>((item) => FruitResponse.fromJson(item))
        .toList();

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Pick Fruit',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Pick Fruit"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  hint: Text("Select Fruit"),
                  value: selectedName,
                  isDense: true,
                  onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedName = newValue;
                    });
                    print(selectedName);
                  },
                  items: _fruitResponse.map((FruitResponse map) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: map.nameDescription,
                      child: Text(map.nameDescription),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class FruitResponse {
  final String nameid;
  final String nameDescription;

  FruitResponse({this.nameid, this.nameDescription});
  factory FruitResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new FruitResponse(nameid: json['id'], nameDescription: json['name']);
  }
}
```

However, my JSON data will be

```
{"objects":[{"id":"e20c","name":"Apples","type":"fruit"},{"id":"a24e","name":"Oranges","type":"fruit"},{"id":"f2a0","name":"Bananas","type":"fruit"}],"from":1,"to":3,"total":3}
```

I have used https://app.quicktype.io/ to generate the following

```
FruitResponse fruitResponseFromJson(String str) => FruitResponse.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String fruitResponseToJson(FruitResponse data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class FruitResponse {
    List<Object> objects;
    int from;
    int to;
    int total;

    FruitResponse({
        this.objects,
        this.from,
        this.to,
        this.total,
    });

    factory FruitResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FruitResponse(
        objects: List<Object>.from(json["objects"].map((x) => Object.fromJson(x))),
        from: json["from"],
        to: json["to"],
        total: json["total"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "objects": List<dynamic>.from(objects.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "from": from,
        "to": to,
        "total": total,
    };
}

class Object {
    String id;
    String name;
    String type;

    Object({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.type,
    });

    factory Object.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Object(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        type: json["type"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "type": type,
    };
}
```

When I replace the class FruitResponse with the updated class FruitResponse and make changes to the items map I get an error.

> Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no instance method 'map' with matching

Working example in DartPad here https://dartpad.dev/b54d896aa35c159cd1749d5c67db7d52

Non-working example in DartPad here
https://dartpad.dev/0413fb4bb7944ccd378b9eabf4e88ff3

I think the problem is just getting the `List<Object>` names correctly from the json data and using it in the DropDownButton items value. I know that `map.objects.toString()` is not correct, but I don't know what to put there or if I am missing something with _fruitResponse.

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm struggling with understanding mapping JSON response list data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Check out the following example i have created using the json, i have parsed the json locally :

Following is the json :

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "id": "e20c",
            "name": "Apples",
            "type": "fruit"
        },
        {
            "id": "a24e",
            "name": "Oranges",
            "type": "fruit"
        },
        {
            "id": "f2a0",
            "name": "Bananas",
            "type": "fruit"
        }
    ],
    "from": 1,
    "to": 3,
    "total": 3
}
```

Depending on the json i have created the model class :

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final fruitResponse = fruitResponseFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

FruitResponse fruitResponseFromJson(String str) => FruitResponse.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String fruitResponseToJson(FruitResponse data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class FruitResponse {
    List<Object> objects;
    int from;
    int to;
    int total;

    FruitResponse({
        this.objects,
        this.from,
        this.to,
        this.total,
    });

    factory FruitResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FruitResponse(
        objects: List<Object>.from(json["objects"].map((x) => Object.fromJson(x))),
        from: json["from"],
        to: json["to"],
        total: json["total"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "objects": List<dynamic>.from(objects.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "from": from,
        "to": to,
        "total": total,
    };
}

class Object {
    String id;
    String name;
    String type;

    Object({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.type,
    });

    factory Object.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Object(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        type: json["type"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "type": type,
    };
}
```

And later the main class where the i have defined the dropdown :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'dummy.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UploadImageState createState() => _UploadImageState();
}

class _UploadImageState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  List<Object> objectList = List();

  Future<String> loadFromAssets() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('json/parse.json');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    loadYourData();
  }

  loadYourData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    String jsonString = await loadFromAssets();
    final fruitResponse = fruitResponseFromJson(jsonString);
    objectList = fruitResponse.objects;
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String selectedFruit;

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.red, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 0.80),
                ),
                child: DropdownButton(
                    value: selectedFruit,
                    isExpanded: true,
                    icon: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                    ),
                    iconSize: 25,
                    underline: SizedBox(),
                    onChanged: (newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        print(newValue);
                        selectedFruit = newValue;
                      });
                      print(selectedFruit);
                    },
                    hint: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text('Select'),
                    ),
                    items: objectList.map((data) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: data.id.toString(),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                          child: Text(
                            data.name,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sugar. I made a few corrections to get it to work [here](https://gist.github.com/SowellM/354941d88bef84f608d070f2ad5d3d71).

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful then you can make an upvote now.

Answer (score 0):

For example listaCatalogo.partes is a list of Object:

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<Catalogo>> _itemsPartes() {
    var provider = Provider.of<CatalogNotifier>(context);

    return provider.listaCatalogo.partes
        .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<Catalogo>(
              value: item,
              child: Text(item.valor),
            ))
        .toList();
  }

DropdownButton<Catalogo>(
                        value: registro.parteCat,
                        onChanged: (Catalogo value) {
                          setState(() {
                            registro.parteCat = value;
                            registro.parte = value.id;
                          });
                        },
                        items: _itemsPartes(),
                      )
```

Answer (score -1):

I give u the idea, you must to change the String to Object

Replace DropdownButton to DropdownButton Where FruitResponse is the OBject that you want to use.

And

```
Replace onChanged: (String newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedName = newValue;
                    });
                    print(selectedName);
                  }
```

to

```
onChanged: (FruitResponse newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedName = newValue.nameid;
                    });
                    print(selectedName);
                  }
```

And DropdownMenuItem to DropdownMenuItem